# Getting Empty array on INNER query in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie in `PHP/MySQL` and this is my first question on stackoverflow, so please ignore any mistake if I have made any.

I am trying to get records from a table through this query.

```
$CId = $this->input->post('Child_id'); //child_id is the value from a textfield

$r_detail = ("SELECT *
            FROM `result_details`
            WHERE ResultId
            IN (SELECT Result_Id
            FROM `results`
            WHERE childId = '".$CId." ')  " );
```

this query is returning an empty `$r_detail`. However when I query the same statement in PHPMyAdmin in localhost and change `"$CID"` to a number, I get the desired records.

Any Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using codeigniter??

Answer (score 1):

You have a space in `INNER JOIN` `WHERE`: `'".$CId." '` should be `'".$CId."'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $r_detail  = ("SELECT *
        FROM `result_details`
        WHERE ResultId
        IN (SELECT Result_Id
        FROM `results`
        WHERE childId = '".$CId." ')  " );
```

has just string...you need to call some db function to get the data such as in code igniter may be

```
  $this->db->query($r_detail);
```